# How can I make sure my JDBC CSV file updates from DB to most recent information?

Tags: java, mysql, intellij-idea, jdbc

I am using a JDBC GUI for a MySQL database on intellij, it worked fine initially but now the data being displayed is old data. It won't update if I edit the DB. 
I've tried setting autocommit to 0 and 1, neither made a difference, also placing them at either the start or the end of the DB and no joy. Extremely new to all this so clueless right now. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Most of the database client applications does not refresh the resultset automatically, there should be a refresh button some where in the UI you have to refresh it to see the latest data.

Comment: Do you mean data from tables or you made changes to database structure like modifying table structure and it does not update in database object window?

Comment: Thanks both. I mean that I ran the program initially, which fed out my DB details from mySql to the CSV, which outputted as a CSV window in intelliJ, but since altering the table (little things like adding a primary key field, changing names) the output is still the old data, old names and no primary key field)